# Send Context to base template using django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Hi i have a ( base template) and need to display all sections in a drop-down-list 
so how can i send a context with the Section objects to display them in a for loop ?

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
     {% for sec in Sections %}
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{sec.section_name}}</a>
     {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: In your views,  let say
```
def Foo(request):

      Sections = Sections.objects.all()
      
      context = {
            'Sections': Sections,
      }
      return render(request, your_base.html, context)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to pass context to the base template, that sounds like the job for a context processor...

1. In your app directory, create a file, `context_processors.py`. In it, add your variable to context... something like:

```py
from yourapp.models import Sections

def sections_to_base(request):    
    sections = Sections.objects.all()    
    return {'sections': sections}
```

2. Add the path to the processor in your project settings. e.g:

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join( BASE_DIR, 'templates' )],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages', 

                'myapp.context_processors.sections_to_base', # <-- this
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

3. At `base.html`, just like you had interpolated:

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
     {% for sec in sections %}
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{sec.section_name}}</a>
     {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you clearly, try this

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
     <li>
     {% for sec in Sections %}
       <ul><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{sec.section_name}}</a></ul>
     {% endfor %}
     </li>
</div>
```